# Spring batch Partitioning with multiple steps running in Sequentially?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have requirement to create a master step with multiple Slaves steps running sequentially. I am able to define single slave inside in master but I need to run slaves sequentially.

```
@Primary
@Profile(MASTER)
@Bean("masterStep")
public Step partitionCreateStepForRemote(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
                            @Qualifier("slave1") Step step,
                            MatchAsyncConfig asyncConfig,
                            MatchingAccountPartitioner partitioner,
                            JMSPartitionHandler messageChannelPartitionHandler,
                            JobRepository jobRepository,
                            @Qualifier("stepLocator") StepLocator stepLocator
)                 {

 SimpleStepExecutionSplitter splitter = new SimpleStepExecutionSplitter();
splitter.setPartitioner(partitioner);
splitter.setJobRepository(jobRepository);

return stepBuilderFactory.get("masterStep")
        .partitioner(step)
        .partitionHandler(messageChannelPartitionHandler)
        .splitter(splitter)
        .taskExecutor(asyncConfig.getAsyncExecutor())
        .build();
}
```

Is There any way to define multiple slaves steps in single master step under same partitioner like below?

```
public Step partitionCreateStepForRemote(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
                            @Qualifier("slave1") Step step,
                            @Qualifier("slave2") Step step,
                            @Qualifier("slave3") Step step, 
                            MatchAsyncConfig asyncConfig,
                            MatchingAccountPartitioner partitioner,
                            JMSPartitionHandler messageChannelPartitionHandler,
                            JobRepository jobRepository,
                            @Qualifier("stepLocator") StepLocator stepLocator
)                 {}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlL9x.png)

Comment: If you need to run things in sequence, why are you looking for partitioning? You can create sequential steps where each step processes a portion of the data.

Comment: It is something like, slave1 , slave2 and slave3 are part of Slave steps for same partitioner. so that each partition can run all child slave steps parallel..

Comment: edit and add image as per requirement

Comment: According to your diagram, this is not slaves running in sequence. You have step1 -> step 2 (with 3 slaves running in parallel) -> step3 -> step4 -> step 5. Your `Slave child 1` from top to bottom are step3, step4, step5 respectively, running in sequence after step 2 is finished.

Comment: My slave has to do multiple operation which i wanted to make in separate steps. That's why we are looking if we can make multiple child slave steps.  like master -> slave ->  slave child 1 -> slave child 2 -> slave child 3. so that i can run all slaves parallel with same partitioner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just need to define Flow inside of slave step. That flow will works as sequential. 
Slave Step is nothing but defining all child Steps internally. So all Slave Steps are running parallel and each slave is running Child Slave Steps sequential.

```
/**
 * @param stepBuilderFactory   step for run each partition
 * @return Step step 6 partition match
 */
@Profile({SINGLE, SLAVE})  //Not applicable for MASTER profile in remote partitioning case
@Bean("slaveStep")
public Step slaveStep(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
                               @Qualifier("readFromFileFlow") Flow flow
) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("slaveStep")
            .listener(stepListener())
            .flow(flow)
            .build();
}

@Profile({SINGLE, SLAVE})
@Bean
public ChildSlaveListener stepListener(){
    return new ChildSlaveListener();
}

@Profile({SINGLE, SLAVE})
@Bean("readFromFileFlow")
public Flow readFromFileFlow(@Qualifier("childSlaveStep1") Step childSlaveStep1,
                             @Qualifier("childSlaveStep2") Step childSlaveStep2) {
    // @formatter:off
    return new FlowBuilder<Flow>("readFromFileFlow")
            .start(childSlaveStep1)
            .on(FAILED).fail()
            .from(childSlaveStep1)
            .on(COMPLETED).to(childSlaveStep2)
            .start(childSlaveStep2)
            .on(FAILED).fail()
            .from(childSlaveStep2)
            .on(COMPLETED).end()
            .end();
    // @formatter:on
}
```